# Rails 3 and Devise: authenticating a user while performing a POST action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

Using Rails 3.0.6, Omniauth 0.2.0 and Devise 1.2.1, I'm encountering the following situation:

I want to offer users the option to authenticate via Facebook.  I have a user system set up using Devise and I can successfully auth using Facebook.  I've spent several hours trying to code the behavior I want for one specific situation:

- user is not logged in
- user has a site account
- user authenticates via Facebook

I offer the user 2 choices at this point

- create an account (can be a dummy account with no provided info)
- link this Facebook authentication with an existing account

I'm having trouble with the latter option.  The user has already authenticated but I still need him to log in with his site account.  I have an action in my `AuthenticationsController` that will associate this authentication with a logged in user.  Devise doesn't seem to offer a way for me to log the user in while staying in the same action, though.  This was my first attempt to do this

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :auth_link_existing_user

  ...

  def auth_link_existing_user
   ...
  end
```

However, using this method, if the user logs in, they're simply redirected to my site's root page.  I know I can change Devise's sign-in redirect, but that will be for all sign-ins.  I wanted only this situation to have a separate redirect.

After reading through [this](http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-06?_done=/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_frm/month/2010-06?&) mailing list question, I tried to extend `SessionsController` with my own custom behavior:

```
def create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#new")
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  if params[:redirect]                            #new
    redirect_to params[:redirect].to_sym          #new
  else
    respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
  end

end
```

This doesn't work either.  I've defined my `auth_link_existing_user` route to use a POST verb (which seems accurate) and redirects can only be GETs.

So now I do have a solution in mind: copy and paste code from Devise's `authenticate_user!` helper into a new function which can be called within a controller action without redirecting.  This seems less than ideal to me because it's duplication of code and increases coupling--a Devise or Warden update that changes this behavior will break my code as well.

Has anyone else tried something like this and come up with a more elegant solution?  Do you see a simpler way for me to offer this or similar behavior to my users?

UPDATE: For anyone who wants to use my dirty solution at the end, this is what I did:

```
def auth_link_existing_user
  # FROM Devise/sessions/create
  resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => :user, :recall => "registrations#auth_new")
  set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
  sign_in(:user, resource)

  # method defined in Ryan Bates' Railscast for Omniauth w/Devise
  current_user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
  current_user.save
end
```

note that this action **MUST** be placed in your sessions controller.  If not, Warden will give you an "invalid email/password" error.  It was an incredibly long debugging process to find the source.

With this in place, I use a login form to submit to this action after the user has authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I like how clean your solution is, though it goes deeper into the stack.

Here is how I've implemented something similar by following the Devise+Omniauth Facebook example on the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview) and modifying the `facebook` method to pass on the session information to the Login form, with something like this:

```
if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication

else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_session_url
end
```

Then, in your case, I'd check in Login controller action for `session["devise.facebook_data"]`, submit the uid + token with the form and apply_omniauth if present.